# Firefox: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: apache2, firefox

I know this has been asked before, but have there been any changes recently?

My server machine runs under Ubuntu-18.04 Server (+ lxde).
It has apache-2.4.29 with 2 domains, both with http and https.
It also has a mail server, citadel-917, which has its own webserver for webmail.
At boot up apache2 should use ports 80 and 443, and citadel should use 8080 and 8081.

But Firefox-65.0 gets "Secure Connection Failed.  Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"
despite "sudo systemctl restart apache2" working without errors and opening port 443.
How can Apache2 and Firefox produce no intelligible error messages when it the system not working?
And how do I fix it? or even find out what is wrong?

I have updated my LetsEncrypt certificates and stared at the conf files and they all look OK.
I have done "apachectl configtest" and it says "syntax OK".
"netstat -nlp" shows port 80 and 443 are listening, but only for tcp6, not tcp, is this right?
gufw-report shows 443 applies to both TCP and TCP(v6).
/var/log/apache2/error.log is OK.
"curl https://mydomain.com" produces:
curl:  (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
I have had this working before a recent clean install.

Can anyone recommend web server software that produces intelligible error messages?

Comment: I Also get that error when I mistake http with https...

Comment: It is strange that port 80 and 443 are not listening for tcp. As to SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG, maybe that page could help you: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/ssl_error_rx_record_too_long/

Comment: I can confirm it is NOT listening on 80tcp or 443tcp.

Comment: Have you run `a2enmod ssl`?

Comment: > a2emod ssl  ?Yes